# Multiple for_loops using and listing

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to create a program where i throw 10 times with a dice. After the 10 throws, i want to put the sum of the throws (like 29 or 40) in a list. After that i will again throw 10 times with the dice and i also want to put the sum of the throws in the same list and so on till i have 10 sums of 10*10 throws

```
import random
repeat = 10
throws = 10
throwsum= []
worpenlijst = []
for j in range(repeat):
    for i in range(throws):
        worpenlijst.append(random.randint(1,6))
throwsum.append(sum(worpenlijst))
throwsum
```

Possible output:

```
throwsum = [33,31,41,29,26,41,33,27,35,36]
```

Comment: indent `throwsum.append(sum(worpenlijst))` so its inside the first for loop and reset the `worpenlijst` after you sum it

Comment: You're going to need to empty `worpenlijst` each outer iteration. Also, generally, please explain what's failing when you post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the list of sums, I'd say use a list comprehension to make things cleaner

```
import random
repeat = 10
throws = 10
throwsum = [sum([random.randint(1, 6) for throw_num in range(throws)]) for repeat_num in range(repeat)]
# [35, 36, 40, 38, 43, 31, 36, 43, 43, 30]
```

Beyond a list comprehension, there's no reason to make that inner list: you can just track the sum:

```
import random
repeat = 10
throws = 10
throwsum= []
for j in range(repeat):
    total = 0 
    for i in range(throws):
        total += random.randint(1,6)
    throwsum.append(total)
print(throwsum)
# [31, 38, 29, 37, 34, 31, 32, 43, 40, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

Identation is needed like following:

```
import random
repeat = 10
throws = 10
throwsum= []
worpenlijst = []
for j in range(repeat):
    for i in range(throws):
        worpenlijst.append(random.randint(1,6))
    throwsum.append(sum(worpenlijst))
throwsum
```

Comment: Also need to empty the `worpenlijst` after summing

Answer (score 0):

```
import random


repeats = 10
throws = 10
sums = []
for _ in range(throws):
    current_res = []
    for _ in range(repeats):
        current_res.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    sums.append(sum(current_res))

print(sums)
```

Comment: Thank you, i can only accept 1 answer, but this one is also very good